# VBA List to be put in sticker format

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

I have a list of data which needs to be printed out on stickers (imagine the Avery kind). I'm having trouble coming up with the code that will produce the desired result:

My code thus far is:

```
With wsEtiketten
    ' erase old data
    .Cells.Clear
    ' enter new data
    With .Cells(1, 2)
        .Value = "Lettrine"
        .Font.Bold = True
    End With
    .Cells(2, 2).Value = sAuswertungsLettrine
    For i = 0 To MaxRow - 1
        For j = 0 To 4
            r.Copy .Cells(4, 2).Offset(i * 5, j * 5)
            .Cells(4, 2).Offset((i * 5) + 1, (j * 5) + 0) = wsSheet.ListObjects(1).DataBodyRange.Cells(i + 1, 1).Value 'Page
            .Cells(4, 2).Offset((i * 5) + 1, (j * 5) + 1) = wsSheet.ListObjects(1).DataBodyRange.Cells(i + 1, 2).Value 'Ordernr
            .Cells(4, 2).Offset((i * 5) + 1, (j * 5) + 2) = wsSheet.ListObjects(1).DataBodyRange.Cells(i + 1, 8).Value 'Surf
            .Cells(4, 2).Offset((i * 5) + 1, (j * 5) + 3) = wsSheet.ListObjects(1).DataBodyRange.Cells(i + 1, 9).Value 'Indice DB
            .Cells(4, 2).Offset((i * 5) + 3, (j * 5) + 0) = wsSheet.ListObjects(1).DataBodyRange.Cells(i + 1, 3).Value 'Count
            .Cells(4, 2).Offset((i * 5) + 3, (j * 5) + 1) = wsSheet.ListObjects(1).DataBodyRange.Cells(i + 1, 4).Value 'CA Brut
            .Cells(4, 2).Offset((i * 5) + 3, (j * 5) + 3) = wsSheet.ListObjects(1).DataBodyRange.Cells(i + 1, 7).Value 'Marge
        Next j
    Next i
End With
```

The information which is tied to it is simply repeated across the row. I need i to change every time the field is offset. How can I do that? I'm sure this is probably programming kindergarden stuff but I'm not getting it.

Thanks!

Comment: Just to help you in searching for answers: Those "stickers (the Avery kind)" are called "labels".

Comment: if the cells are repeated, couldn't you just `=MyRepeatedCell` for all the other cells, and then just alter 1 cell, instead of looping through all the other cells that have the same value. This would reduce it to about 8 operations instead of 100's

Comment: Hi Sean, not sure if I understood your comment correctly, but I have different data in every cell. Nothing repeats.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok. I managed to come up with an answer within Excel. Once I had it, it was obvious.
Here goes:

```
With wsEtiketten
    ' Alte Daten werden gelöscht
    .Cells.Clear
    ' Neue Daten werden eingelesen
    With .Cells(1, 2)
        .Value = "Lettrine"
        .Font.Bold = True
    End With
    .Cells(2, 2).Value = sAuswertungsLettrine
    For i = 0 To MaxRow - 1
            r.Copy .Cells(4, 2).Offset(WorksheetFunction.RoundDown(i / 5, 0) * 5, ((i + 5) Mod 5) * 5)
            .Cells(4, 2).Offset((WorksheetFunction.RoundDown(i / 5, 0)) * 5 + 1, ((i + 5) Mod 5) * 5 + 0) = wsSheet.ListObjects(1).DataBodyRange.Cells(i + 1, 1).Value 'Page
            .Cells(4, 2).Offset((WorksheetFunction.RoundDown(i / 5, 0)) * 5 + 1, ((i + 5) Mod 5) * 5 + 1) = wsSheet.ListObjects(1).DataBodyRange.Cells(i + 1, 2).Value 'Bestellnummer
            .Cells(4, 2).Offset((WorksheetFunction.RoundDown(i / 5, 0)) * 5 + 1, ((i + 5) Mod 5) * 5 + 2) = wsSheet.ListObjects(1).DataBodyRange.Cells(i + 1, 8).Value 'Surf
            .Cells(4, 2).Offset((WorksheetFunction.RoundDown(i / 5, 0)) * 5 + 1, ((i + 5) Mod 5) * 5 + 3) = wsSheet.ListObjects(1).DataBodyRange.Cells(i + 1, 9).Value 'Indice DB
            .Cells(4, 2).Offset((WorksheetFunction.RoundDown(i / 5, 0)) * 5 + 3, ((i + 5) Mod 5) * 5 + 0) = wsSheet.ListObjects(1).DataBodyRange.Cells(i + 1, 3).Value 'Anzahl
            .Cells(4, 2).Offset((WorksheetFunction.RoundDown(i / 5, 0)) * 5 + 3, ((i + 5) Mod 5) * 5 + 1) = wsSheet.ListObjects(1).DataBodyRange.Cells(i + 1, 4).Value 'CA Brut
            .Cells(4, 2).Offset((WorksheetFunction.RoundDown(i / 5, 0)) * 5 + 3, ((i + 5) Mod 5) * 5 + 3) = wsSheet.ListObjects(1).DataBodyRange.Cells(i + 1, 7).Value 'Marge
    Next i
End With
```

Answer (score 2):

Maybe an answer with an unexpected twist. You can use an Excel table in combination with Word to get the result you want as well. This is standard Office functionality:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/318117/en

or in German:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/318117/de

Comment: Hi K_B, thanks, but I may have confused the issue by writing about labels. I want to know how to do this also for future similar problems. Also, I don't want to tie word into the script as well. Nevertheless thanks for the tipp (and the extra effort of finding the link in german as well)!